# JavaScript Framework to just subscribe & fire custom events?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, frameworks

JavaScript Framework to just listen/subscribe & trigger/fire custom events similar to Backbone.Events?

Just curious if there was any JS mini/micro framework/lib that I am missing...

[Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) does this, but any small framework/lib that *just* does this, or does it simpler/better?

Thanks.

Comment: Interpretation: what does the author mean?

Comment: Backbone.Events is pretty simple, you could extract it in a few minutes or duplicate it in a couple hours.

Comment: you could write your own very easily by just keeping an internal object of `(eventName, callback)` pairs and exposing `publish` and `subscribe` functions.

Comment: making your own would be an awesome learning experience as well. it's surprisingly easy to implement. just as mu is too short said, you can just pull Backbone.Events out of the library. It's 80 lines of code and 32 lines of comments.

Comment: http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked with [Chaplin](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin) which uses the [publish/subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) pattern.
You can look for some "mediators" like [Core.js](http://oscargodson.github.com/Core.js/), [PubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) or [Signal-js](http://millermedeiros.github.com/js-signals/).
Referencing and user feedbacks [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991607/best-publish-subscribe-library-in-javascript).

Comment: PubSub looks like a great library and it appears to not require the use of third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way - provided you're usign jQuery - is to use **[jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** (equivalent to publish) and **[jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** (equivalent to subscribe). Also **[jQuery.unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)** (to unsubscribe).

You can use them with DOM events as well as custom events.

```
//Subsribe to my custom Event
$(document).bind('MyCustomEvent', function() {
  alert('Reacting to my custom event ..');
});

// .... somewhere else in the code, publish the event
jQuery.event.trigger('MyCustomEvent');
//or $(document).trigger('MyCustomEvent');
```

> **[Update from jquery documentation]**
>
> (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to
>   attach and remove event handlers on elements.)